# How to build a maven meta project from sibling projects in gradle

Tags: maven, build, gradle

I have a multi project that has a structure like this:

```
.
├── all
├── left
└── right
```

I am trying to make :all a "composite meta project" of it's siblings (:left and :right). That is :all project should publish just a pom that declares dependency on siblings (it itself contains no code and doesn't produce a jar).

Is this possible? And if so how should I configure :all to achieve it?

I am using gradle 1.12

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared the following example. Maybe I it will help You.

**root/build.gradle** is empty

**root/settings.gradle**

```
include ":l", ":r", ":all"
```

**root/l/build.gradle** is empty

**root/p/build.gradle** is empty

**root/all/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':l')
    compile project(':r')
}

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. Mind that this isn't a full example, rather proof of concept.